# Selenium fails with error: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 2

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am using

- Selenium 3.0.1
- Python 2.7.12
- Firefox 50

I have set the geckodriver's path in `PATH` but still I am getting the below error while running the test:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 2

Also, in `geckodriver.log` in my home directory below is displayed:

> ```
> Usage:
>     geckodriver [OPTIONS]
> geckodriver: Unknown option --port
> ```

Comment: upgrade to a new geckodriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
binary = FirefoxBinary('path/to/installed firefox binary')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

Also dont forget to restart after setting path.

Comment: if firefox can be found via your PATH, there is no need to explicitly set the binary location in your test code.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be using an older version of geckodriver. Do you know what version you're using? [The latest version is 0.11.1](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Comment: I am using 0.9.0 Is the possible cause for this error?

Comment: It could be, there were quite a few fixes since 0.9.0. There's a good chance 0.11.1 will work better for you.

Comment: I just checked the project itself, looks like that option was in fact added for 0.10.0